# why the device file can not be found in init process after kernel booted?

Tags: kernel-module, init, openwrt

everyone, I want to execute a script in init process, and I want it auto restart whenever it be terminated.

so I put this line in /etc/inittab

```
::respawn:/root/test.sh
```

and the test.sh contains this line(I simplified the script for clarify):

```
[ -e /dev/ttyUSB0 ] && echo 'hello, USB0' > /root/dump
```

and then I reboot my system to test the result, unfortunately, I never got a *dump* file in /root/ contains the line '*hello, USB0*', which indicates that the /dev/ttyUSB0 is not exists.

but after I logged in, and type `ls /dev/tty*` I can see that the /dev/ttyUSB0 was right there.

I use openwrt 3.3.8, and I have installed kmod-usb-serial-pl2303 module so openwrt can recognize my usb device.

what's the problem? Is the usb serial module not loaded when init process running? Sorry for my poorly English, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kernel version do you have? Have you enabled **devtmpfs** (`CONFIG_DEVTMPFS` and `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT`) in kernel?

Comment: I suggest you look at openwrt hotplug system. There will be a hotplug event on usb activity. http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/hotplug, /etc/hotplug.d/usb/